# WPF: Resize image but only when user resizes UI

Tags: wpf, image

I have a WPF application which is based on multiple grids. So far it works as expected. The application shows some kind of toolbar at the top and an Image control at the center/bottom. When I resize the window, the Image element resizes as well which is perfectly fine.

Now, when I set the ImageSource to the Image control and the image is large (e.g. vertically), this will cause the whole window to resize vertically as well.

How can I allow the user to resize the window (including resizing the image) but NOT allow a resize operation when an image is loaded into the Image control?

```
<Window x:Class="GrafAoiKyErrorViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:grafAoiKyErrorViewer="clr-namespace:GrafAoiKyErrorViewer"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    Title="Graf AOI KY Error Viewer"
    MinWidth="600"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Icon="Images/AnalyzeTrace_16x.png" MinHeight="800"
    >

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding WindowLoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=SelectNextCommand}" Gesture="F2" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=SelectPreviousCommand}" Gesture="F1" />
</Window.InputBindings>

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <grafAoiKyErrorViewer:ErrorClassToStringConverter x:Key="ErrorClassToStringConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3">Datenbank</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" MinWidth="400" ItemsSource="{Binding AoiDatabaseCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayString" SelectedValue="{Binding AoiDatabaseSelected}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3">Projekt</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" MinWidth="400" ItemsSource="{Binding AoiProjectCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding AoiProjectSelected}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3">Lot</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" MinWidth="400" ItemsSource="{Binding AoiLotCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding AoiLotSelected}" />



    <Grid Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorClassCollection}" Height="200" SelectionMode="Single" MinWidth="200">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item, Converter={StaticResource ErrorClassToStringConverter}}" Header="Fehlerklasse" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionErrorClassAllOnCommand}">Alle Ein</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionErrorClassAllOffCommand}">Alle Aus</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionErrorClassRealErrorsOnlyCommand}">Echte Fehler</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding PositionCollection}" Height="200" SelectionMode="Single" MinWidth="200">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                                    <!--<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Command="{Binding DataContext.FailureSelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />-->
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item}" Header="Position" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionPositionAllOnCommand}">Alle Ein</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionPositionAllOffCommand}">Alle Aus</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ArticleCollection}" Height="200" SelectionMode="Single" MinWidth="200">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item}" Header="Artikel" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionArticleAllOnCommand}">Alle Ein</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionArticleAllOffCommand}">Alle Aus</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding PartTypeCollection}" Height="200" SelectionMode="Single" MinWidth="200">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item}" Header="Bauform" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionPartTypeAllOnCommand}">Alle Ein</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Command="{Binding ModifySelectionPartTypeAllOffCommand}">Alle Aus</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Margin="3" Padding="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding FailureSelectionChangedCommand}">Aktualisieren</Button>
    <Grid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid MinWidth="200">
            <!-- DUMMY GRID -->
        </Grid>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding CurrentFailureItem.KyAoiFailureImage.Image2DData}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Image>

        <!--<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        </Viewbox>-->
        <!--<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" >
            </Border>-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="100" Margin="3" Padding="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SelectPreviousCommand}">Previous</Button>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Padding="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center">
                <Run Text="{Binding SelectedFailureItemIndexDisplay, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
                <Run Text=" / "></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding TotalFailureItemIndex, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="100" Margin="3" Padding="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SelectNextCommand}">Next</Button>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" MinWidth="200">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentFailureItem.Position}" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentFailureItem.Article}" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentFailureItem.PartType}" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentFailureItem.ErrorClass}" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: please share your XAML

Comment: Attached it to the main post. The Image control is near the bottom (it's the only image element at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is actually the intended behaviour of the control however to fix this issue locate this line in your code:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
```

and replace it with this:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MaxHeight="100">
```

while setting the MaxHeight to a reasonable value

EDIT:
OK, understand in this case replace the image with a grid and use its background:

```
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
               <Grid.Background>
                  <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding CurrentFailureItem.KyAoiFailureImage.Image2DData}" Stretch="Uniform"></ImageBrush>
               </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly what I do NOT want. I want the user to be able to resize the window (thereby resizing the image control in both directions) but I don't want the image control to resize the UI (the other way round)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: This seems pretty hacky but works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: glad i could help!
indeed seems to be a wird solution to your issue but to avoid that you would have to keep the window from resizing which is only possible by disabling the resizefeature entirely or by handleing the events yourself
both other methods are eigther bad or not what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting your Image control within a Viewbox:

`<Viewbox>
   <Image ImageSource="{Binding MyImage"/>
</Viewbox>`

You may need to mess about with the Viewbox `Stretch` attribute (I always forget which one does what, but you can usually get one to do what you want with a bit of trial and error).

Comment: I tried with all kinds of variation of Center/Stretch for both Viewbox and the Image but the result was always the same. I also tried the property StretchDirection=DownOnly on the Image control but this also didn't yield the expected result